# Design structure for nextjs and nestjs inside nx monorepo with pnpm

Tags: next.js, nestjs, monorepo, nx.dev

I am planning to [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) app on frontend and [nestjs](https://nestjs.com/) for backend inside NX monorepo using [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) workspace.

I am confused how should I design the complete folder structure.

1. Should I use [package based repo](https://nx.dev/getting-started/package-based-repo-tutorial)?
2. or Should I use [integrated repo](https://nx.dev/getting-started/integrated-repo-tutorial)?
3. or Should I use [pnpm workspace](https://pnpm.io/workspaces) and define the structure as "apps" and "libs" folder in `pnpm-workspace.yaml` and have both nextjs and nestjs app inside `app` folder?

Can anyone with some experience on the above tech stack can share your thoughts/inputs here

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented in any of the three methods.
It depends upon your use case.

### Package based

It gives you flexibility in terms of dependencies. You can use different versions of dependencies based on the project. Using this an exmaple folder structure could be

- apps

  - api
  - web
- libs

  - utils
  - db
  - config

### Integrated repo

It resolves all the dependencies and scripts automatically.

I personally go with package based repo when I know that in future i would want to add a new application to the monorepo with a different version of a dependency. Example : nextjs 12 and nextjs 13 app in the same repo.

I go with integrated repo when i have to get started quickly and not worry about dependencies. This is particularly useful for small projects